# Is the metadata limit on testnet transactions the same as mainnet?

Tags: transaction, metadata, testnet, transaction-metadata

I was wondering if there was a difference in the byte limit in metadata added to test-net transactions versus being done on the main-net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction metadata limit is the same on both networks, as they share [the same ledger rules](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/master/shelley-ma/shelley-ma-test/cddl-files/shelley-ma.cddl#L203-L210).